# Too much spacing between text and equations with the twoside option

Tags: vertical-spacing

I am writing a thesis and I have a problem with the spacing between text and equations. In particular, this problem occurs when I use the `twoside` option in the specification of the document class. I am currently using `\documentclass[12 pt, twoside, raggedbottom, reqno]{report}`
Here an image of what I obtain

[image: text]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please show the code that generates the numbered equation.

Comment: The indentation after the equation suggests that you have an empty line after (and I'd bet also before) the equation, which might lead to the behaviour you observe. Alas, we need to see the actual code as Mico asked.

Comment: never have a blank line before display math, but it is hard to tell you how to correct code you have not shown.